# Create Snippet with variables in Atom

Tags: editor, code-snippets, atom-editor

Is it possible to incorporate variables into snippets in Atom? This comes in handy with for loops for example, when you want to pre-fill spots that are about to come.

The `snippets.cson` entry with java as a source I would imagine. Unfortunately it is not working.

```
'.source.java':
    'For-Loop':
        'prefix': 'fori'
        'body': 'for (int ${1:VAR} = $2; ${VAR} < $3; ${VAR}++) {\n\t$3\n}'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Update 2016-09

This is now supported in Atom - please see the other answer for how to use it. I can't delete this answer since it is the accepted one...

## Old Answer

The documentation for the [snippets package](https://github.com/atom/snippets) has an example that shows how to predefine the default value for a variable:

```
'.source.js':
  'console.log':
    'prefix': 'log'
    'body': 'console.log(${1:"crash"});$2'
```

In the above example, *crash* is used as the default value for the log statement, allowing you to provide your own value by overwriting the *crash* default.

I guess what you're asking is whether there's a way to automatically use a value you typed and then apply it to the other instances of the same placeholder. So in your example, when you're at variable `$1` and type `foo`, that it uses `foo` for all other occurrences of `${VAR}`, right?

That's currently not possible from what I understand. I suggest you open a feature request at the snippets package's repo, or even better take a stab at adding this functionality and then creating a pull request.

Sorry if this doesn't help you, but you asked whether there was a way of doing this with the current version of Atom. The answer seems to be *No* at the present time.

Comment: Well. At least I know. Thanks!

Comment: This is now supported.

Comment: Thanks for the update - I was not aware that this was added.

Comment: FYI, for me `${1:"crash"}` defaults to `"crash"` and not `crash` (ie, don't quote the default values unless you want those quotes). Also note that multiline snippets are possible using `'''` and `"""`.

Answer (score 13):

Current version of Atom can support this kind of snippet. You can just put $1 at every places you want.

```
'.source.coffee':
  'For-Loop':
    'prefix': 'fori'
    'body': 'for (int ${1:i} = $2; ${1:i} < $3; ${1:i}++) {\n\t$4\n}'
```

Comment: As this is now supported, this is the right answer.